# Using guilds and channels without needing to read a message

Tags: discord.js

I'm hosting my bot on glitch.com, but it restarts every night.

When my bot gets started, it reads a message from a specific channel and then writes in the others. The problem with this is that I can't use any guild or channel until the bot receives a message.

How can I avoid doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use guild and channel IDs. Every element in Discord has a unique ID (called [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)) that identifies it.
If you want to get a specific guild or channel, you can save its ID and use it in the code. IDs are public, so there's no risk using them (they're not like passwords or tokens).

Guilds and channels are stored in [Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) and mapped by their IDs, so you can use them like this:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.get('guild id as a string');
let channel = guild.channels.get('channel id as a string');
```

To get your guild's ID (or the ID of pretty much any element in Discord) you can enable the [Developer mode](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) in the settings, then right-click on the guild and select "Copy ID".